# Generate Swagger 2.0 Specification from JAX-RS 1.0 annotation via Java Main class

Tags: swagger, jax-rs, swagger-2.0

I have a legacy project such that we are using JAX-RS 1.x, and Ant builds.

I would like to generate a Swagger Specification via scanning the annotations but.... I don't want to require people to have a running instance of my web application.   Instead, I would like to do it via an Ant task that (perhaps) just invokes a java `main` method that invokes the scanner and writes the specification to an output directory.

I have found lots of documentation on how to generate a Swagger Spec in the context of a running web application, but NOT from a Java `main` application running context.

I do recognize that the URI of the endpoints is not well-defined outside the context of a running web app, but that doesn't concern us because we are mainly interested in generating documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some code that works except for the fact that I can't seem get the `info` stuff into the actual generated JSON

```
    final Info info = new Info();
    info.setTitle(API_TITLE);
    info.setDescription(API_DESCRIPTION);
    info.setVersion(API_VERSION);

    BeanConfig beanConfig = new BeanConfig();

    // TODO Some of these do not seem to end up in the JSON file:
    beanConfig.setTitle(API_TITLE);
    beanConfig.setDescription(API_DESCRIPTION);
    beanConfig.setVersion(API_VERSION);
    beanConfig.setSchemes(new String[]{"https"});
    beanConfig.setHost(HOST);
    beanConfig.setBasePath(BASE_PATH);
    beanConfig.setResourcePackage(RESOURCE_PACKAGE);
    beanConfig.setScan(true);

    beanConfig.setInfo(info);   // TODO - This has no effect

    Swagger swagger = beanConfig.getSwagger();
    swagger.setInfo(info);   // TODO - This has no effect

    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    File outputFile = new File(SWAGGER_OUTPUT_FILE_PATH + SWAGGER_OUTPUT_FILENAME);

    // Force file and directory to be created if it doesn't exist.  Otherwise an error will be thrown when we pass
    // it to ObjectMapper.
    outputFile.getParentFile().mkdirs();  // Force creation of output directory if it doesn't exit
    outputFile.createNewFile();
    objectMapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValue(outputFile, swagger);
```